# Network Address Translation (NAT) when bidirectional socket is established?

Tags: sockets, networking

when client sends a request to server, one entry is inserted in nat table (in router). After client received response, this entry will be deleted. Server can't send message to client if client doesn't issue request (client is in private network)
However in case of bidirectional socket, how to accomplish this issue: 
 
1. How does server actively sends message to client ?

---

[updated from comments]

I want to implement server-push architechture, so I need to know more about NAT.

Comment: The NAT entry is only deleted if the server (or the client) activly shuts down the socket from its side. If the connection wasn't shut down,the server is free to send as much data as it wants.

Comment: However, a NAT may timeout and delete an entry if it is idle for a long time not sending any data back and forth, even though the connection is still alive. Non-FTP-aware NATs cause such a problem for FTP clients, since the command socket is idle while the data socket is transferring data. FTP clients usually enable TCP keepalives to keep a NAT happy during long transfers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it means socket sends idle command after a period of time to keep NAT entry alive. How long is default timeout?

Comment: @alk thanks for your answer. I want to implement server-push architechture, so I need to know more about nat

Comment: So you might like to have a look at STUN. Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

Comment: @alk thanks! I will spend time on reading it :D

Comment: @Hugevn: the default NAT timeout is NAT specific.  The default TCP keepalive timeout is 2 hours. On Windows, you can use [WSAIoctl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220.aspx) to customize the TCP keepalive on a per-connection basis. Some platforms support `TCP_KEEPCNT`, `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, and `TCP_KEEPINTVL` via `setsockopt()` for the same purpose.